# Maven plugin testing with Groovy: access to generated class?

Tags: maven, groovy, integration-testing, maven-plugin

I'm developping a Maven plugin and some of my tests are done through maven-invoker-plugin based on Groovy scripts (https://maven.apache.org/plugin-developers/plugin-testing.html).
This Maven plugin generates a Java class and I'd like to test this generated class behaviour with Groovy scripts.
I'm facing a problem with these Groovy scripts saying that it could not resolve the class:

```
Running post-build script: <blah>\verify.groovy
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Script1.groovy: 21: unable to resolve class com.mycompany.MyClass
 @ line 21, column 1.
   import com.mycompany.MyClass
```

Here is the generated Java class from my plugin:

```
package com.mycompany;

public final class MyClass {

    public static String getSomething() {

        return "something";
    }
}
```

Here is an extract of my Groovy test `verify.groovy`:

```
File generatedJavaFile = new File( basedir, "target/my-plugin/com/mycompany/MyClass.java" );
assert generatedJavaFile.exists()
assert generatedJavaFile.isFile()

File generatedClassFile = new File( basedir, "target/classes/com/mycompany/MyClass.class" );
assert generatedClassFile.exists()
assert generatedClassFile.isFile()

import com.mycompany.MyClass

assert MyClass.getSomething() == "the expected result"
```

I was wondering if something needs to be specified to the maven-invoker-plugin configuration to include the tested Maven project, or if it's just not possible and I need to find another way...

Thanks,
Benoît.

Comment: The execution of `verify.groovy` has not your class on the classpath...so you can't import them and use them...Apart from that you should write unit/integration tests inside the project you are using in the integration test where you can completely use those generated classes...